# Remove class after slideUp initiates but before it finishes (callbacks)

Tags: jquery, callback

This is the first piece of code I've looked at in Jquery and I've encountered a problem. The HTML is in the fiddle.

**Problem**

What you'll notice with the slideup callback function is it will wait 300 seconds before removing the active class. So if you click a panel and then click another panel within 0.3 seconds second, you will have 2 panels unfolded as at the time of the click there are 2 active classes. Is there a way to fix this?

**JSfiddle test**

Test it in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpkxmfyg/) by clicking on any panel, and then quickly clicking on another panel within 1 second.

(Obviously I could reduce the time it takes to slide up, but currently I have it at 0.3s and I just dont want it to break incase someone clicks on it quickly...)

```
$(function(){
    $(".tab-panels .tabs li").on("click", function(){
        //show panel with class="active"
        var panelToShow = $(this).attr("rel");
        $(".tab-panels .panel.active").slideUp(300, function(){
            $(this).removeClass("active", function(){
                $("#"+panelToShow).slideDown(300, function() {
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });

            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You may use .stop(). http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the previous animation and try

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tab-panels .tabs li").on("click", function() {
    //show panel with class="active"
    var panelToShow = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(".tab-panels .panel.active").stop().slideUp(1000, function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
      $("#" + panelToShow).slideDown(1000, function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.tab-panels ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.tab-panels ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tab-panels ul li:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #666;
}
.tab-panels ul li.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #666;
}
.tab-panels .panel {
  display: none;
  background: #c9c9c9;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  width: 222px;
}
.tab-panels .panel {
  display: none;
}
.tab-panels .panel.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-panels">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li rel="panel1">Panel 1</li>
    <li rel="panel2">Panel 2</li>
    <li rel="panel3">Panel 3</li>
    <li rel="panel4">Panel 4</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="panel1" class="panel active">
    <p>Content 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="panel2" class="panel" )>
    <p>Content 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="panel3" class="panel">
    <p>Content 3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="panel4" class="panel">
    <p>Content 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```